# SuperNote A5X - Cannot download

Tags: custom-roms, download-manager

I've got a SuperNote A5X and I've installed some extra apps to make my experience better. I'd like to be able to download files (such as via a browser or cloud-storage app). None of these work on it. Some examples are:

- Most apps (Tor Browser, EInkBro, Midori Browser) just say "downloading" and do nothing
- Some (Proton Drive) fail with an error `"system could not find any application that could create a document"`

I believe need to install some sort of download manager for these to work, but I can't seem to find any. I also tried to copy my phone's apk to the supernote, but it didn't work because of SDK incompatibility (Phone was ~30, SuperNote was 27).

*p.s. Please don't skip reading and then tell me to reset the device to get the factory app back, like in all the other similar posts. **There is no factory app.***

Comment: The SuperNote A5X may base on Android but is it really designed to be equipped with third party apps? May be the manufacturer removed certain services and apps that are installed by default that are required by other apps. E.g. there is by default a Download Manager running as system service. Copying such APKs form other devices will most likely fail because they don't have the correct signature.

Comment: Yes, it's not technically designed to, and the devs have said that it's not officially supported. However, I'm not installing anything that is wildly dissimilar to the stock apps. ProtonMail - Built in email app; ProtonDrive - Supernote Partner App; etc. All I need is a way to get files onto the device without having to use my laptop or phone or other device. I can't though because the download provider (as far as I'm aware) doesn't exist. Would something like https://alternativeto.net/software/free-download-manager/about/ work?

Comment: If the SuperNote A5X is not an Google Android device (no Google apps installed = device not certified by Google) then it is not a regular Android device and thus you can not expect that a common store app works. Too many components (besides the obvious Google services) can be missing. In your case it seems that there is no DownloadManager included in the ROM, so you can not use apps that require a DownloadManager.